# Login failed error when using Entity Framework code-first in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and trying to create database by using EF code-first using latest version of Entity Framework and it keeps get error of login user failed.

I checked every question about that problem but none of them fix that bug, 
like :[Entity Framework Login Failed Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106867/entity-framework-login-failed-error)

[EF6 Code First: Login Failing on update-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115195/ef6-code-first-login-failing-on-update-database)

[EF Code First - creating database - Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985854/ef-code-first-creating-database-login-failed-for-user)

That is my connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ROCKY-PC\ROCKYSQL;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

My context class

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace testNox.Models
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have no idea where I went wrong, I tested connection several times and succeeded.

Note: everything is fine with database first but with code-first nothing get better in every time I try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of testing ,the problem solved.
i put a break point in `context class` and run it, i figured out that the execution didn't pass it so I added values to entities class in order to execute `context class` and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It will happened because your sql server user don't have appropriate access rights for your database. In my case, I had create new login user and give him all rights which are required(add username and password in connectionstring). That's solve my all login and permission related issues.

[SQL SERVER – Add Any User to SysAdmin Role – Add Users to System Roles](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/27/sql-server-add-any-user-to-sysadmin-role-add-users-to-system-roles/)